# How to visualize a FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

I have upload a kml file including main metropolitans in us as a fusion table, I can print the featurecollection but cann't visualize it in code editor.What's wrong with my code?

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1Eii75QFBlQcYILLBFsU6zv9LhgJLa8FPHNGSZijQ')

Map.addLayer(fc, {}, 'metro');


print('fc',fc)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the property to use as the geometry by passing it as the second parameter to ee.FeatureCollection:

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1Eii75QFBlQcYILLBFsU6zv9LhgJLa8FPHNGSZijQ', "geometry")
```

Comment: Awesome! Brief answer makes a big difference!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, you uploaded that KML file with the geometry set as a property of the feature, instead of the actual geometry of that feature. With this code, you can get the geometry of the property of each feature, return each feature with it's other properties and the geometry set as geometry:

```
var withGeometry = fc.map(function(feat){
  var geom = ee.Geometry(feat.get('geometry'));
  var propNames = feat.propertyNames().remove('geometry');
  var props = feat.toDictionary(propNames);
  return ee.Feature(geom, props);
});
print(withGeometry)
Map.addLayer(withGeometry.draw('red'),{}, 'feat collection')
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9afc2ba29d246751f2e78dcff98e4af9)